# What comments are copied when a question is migrated?

Tags: support, migrated-questions

I migrated a question from [Drupal Answers](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/41986/insert-submitted-form-content-to-db-using-drupal-write-record?noredirect=1) to [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12317031/insert-submitted-form-content-to-db-using-drupal-write-record), and I noticed my comment was not copied, while an answer I converted to a comment was.

> [image: Drupal answers]
>
> [image: Stack Overflow]

Was my comment not migrated because I am a moderator on Drupal Answers, or for other reasons? What are the criteria used to migrate comments?

Comment: Your comment has a link to the destination site homepage. That should do it

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Comments that include a link to the site that ends up being the destination of a migration aren't ported over since most of them, like yours, just say "this question belongs on $destinationSite".